# Vue unit test error: expected [Function: proxy] to be false

Tags: unit-testing, vuejs2, chai, karma-mocha

> Vue unit test error: expected [Function: proxy] to be false

The function in the Vue component is:

```
data(){
   return{
      showcart:false
   }
}

methods:{
   closedialoguebox: function() {
      return (this.showcart = false);
   }
}
```

and the unit test case for the respective function is:

it('closedialoguebox function should close the dialogue box when clicked on home', () => {

```
const Mockedshowcart = false
const someStub = sinon.stub(wrapper.vm,'closedialoguebox').returns(Mockedshowcart)
expect(someStub).to.be.false
```

})
}

and the error i'm getting is :

```
× closedialoguebox function should close the dialogue box when clicked on home
    expected [Function: proxy] to be false
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`someStub` is a function that returns `false`.
Your test case is not calling the function `someStub`. Add the parentheses to call the function. The correct statement is:

`expect(someStub()).to.be.false`